# HTML5 border-bottom is displayed wrong(?)

Tags: css, html, border

Can't set the border property at the bottom of my html window/viewport...

It's just after the last html element. e.g. div.

Is there a way, so it will be displayed really at the bottom of the window?
Here is my css:

```
html {
   border-bottom:5px solid rgb(17,17,17);
   border-top:5px solid rgb(17,17,17);
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry, but what border? What div?

Comment: Provide relevant code.

Comment: No div, I'm talking about the whole document.

`html {
 border-bottom:5px;
 border-bottom-color:rgb(17,17,17);
 border-bottom-style:solid;
 border-top:5px;
 border-top-color:rgb(17,17,17);
 border-top-style:solid;
}`

Comment: That should be `border-bottom-width` but not `border-bottom`... same for `border-top`..

Comment: border-bottom-height maybe, yes... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html add

```
html { 
    width:100%;
    /*height:99%; Fallback for older browsers*/
    height:calc(100% - 10px);       
    border-bottom:5px solid rgb(17,17,17);
    border-top:5px solid rgb(17,17,17);
}
```

I think this will fix your problem.

Here is the <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xg9Y6/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: That works kind of. But I automatically get a scrollbar to scroll down to see the border.

Comment: @fooness if you have scroll bar adjust the height..

Comment: Hm. Can I have something like 100%-5px?

Comment: Try `height:calc(100% - 10px);`

Comment: Accept the answer so it will helpful for other users.

Comment: Done, thanks! But I can't vote it up yet, sorry.

Comment: It's ok, do it when you have rights.

Comment: BTW, it does not seem that you need margin and padding. Just setting height and width seems to work, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your body tags margin and padding to 0px.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify width and height.

```
html{
    border-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom-color:rgb(17, 17, 17);
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-top:5px;
    border-top-color:rgb(17, 17, 17);
    border-top-style:solid;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

(here's an imgur album to compare the difference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fiM2.jpg notice how in the first image, there's a whitespace under it, which appears to be your issue, whereas with height and width, it reaches the bottom of the document)

Edit: And if you have issues with a scrollbar, try 99%, or 99.5%, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I get a scrollbar and have to scroll down to see the border.

Comment: As I have said in the edit, mess around with it. Try 99% height. Hell, do 99% height, and instead of a 5px border, do a 0.5% border.